# SurfaceView is not showing in frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to implement UI where there is a transparent `listView`and a `SurfaceView`running a video running in the background they are both put in `Framelayout`

Here is the xml layout :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/surfaceFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:entries="@array/some_array">

</ListView>
```

This layout is being inflated to a `FragmentActivity` and it is working fine but if I put this Activity inside a little complicated hierarchy (like tabHost) the `SurfaceView` is not displaying the video I can hear the volume of the video but the `SurfaceView` is displaying a blank view and if I put the`SurfaceView` above the `ListView` it become the first View in the **whole window** meaning that it will overlap other things like `NavigationDrawer` 
Can someone explain what is going on ?

I am really confused about this

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use a relative layout to have the listview over the surfaceview? I wouldn't recommend using frame layouts as your root layout. I would either use a relative layout (for stacked views) or a linear layout (for ordered views). Frame layouts are generally used as placeholders and not containers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but that did not solve my problem.